Is there way to inject mouse actions inside a browser with no relying on cdp or js or sys wide solutions
hi is there way to make mouse  actions drag and drop for browser with no relying on cdp or js or sys wide solusions also besides my solution fails cause of browser instance not launching inside of vd


##################
browser launched in corect display for 
    #from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
    #display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
    #display.start() 

byt as far i know no way to control mouse actions 


################



class DisplayWindow:
    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        self.display = Xlib.display.Display()
        self.screen = self.display.screen()

        # Create window attributes manually
        self.attributes = {
            "background_pixel": self.screen.white_pixel,
            "event_mask": Xlib.X.ExposureMask | Xlib.X.ButtonPressMask,
            "border_width": 10,
            "depth": self.screen.root_depth,
            "class": Xlib.X.InputOutput,
            "visual": Xlib.X.CopyFromParent
        }

        self.window = self.create_window(width, height)
        self.set_window_title(title)

    def create_window(self, width, height):
        return self.screen.root.create_window(
            0, 0,  # x, y coordinates
            width, height,  # width, height
            **self.attributes  # Use dictionary unpacking for attributes
        )

    def set_window_title(self, title):
        self.window.set_wm_name(title)

    def launch_display(self):
        self.window.map()
        self.display.sync()
        print(f"Display ID ---->{ self.display.get_display_name()}")

    async def drag_and_drop(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):

        self.window.warp_pointer(x1, y1)
        self.display.sync()

        # Simulate left mouse button press
        fake_input(self.display, Xlib.X.ButtonPress, 1)
        self.display.sync()

        # Move the mouse pointer to the ending coordinates
        self.window.warp_pointer(x2, y2)
        self.display.sync()

        # Simulate left mouse button release
        fake_input(self.display, Xlib.X.ButtonRelease, 1)
        self.display.sync()

 ###### some coide heare ##########


    #display_window.launch_display()
    #os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'

    #def is_display_available(display_id):
    #    try:
    #        display = Xlib.display.Display(display_id)
    #        return True
    #    except Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError:
    #        return False



    
  

    #if not is_display_available(':0'): 
    #    print("Virtual display is not available")
    #    exit(1)

launching asynic browser chrome and making actions 

    

i tried  js injection failed cause of same origin policy tried pyautogui failed not suitable for task tried selenium methods failed cause of detection of cdp and many more

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Selenium uses Wire Protocol... so maybe just use geckodriver and Selenium?  The question isn't all that clear.  Kinda sounds like you're trying to evade bot detection and that's a moving target.  If you have to avoid Seleniun, OS-level robot-like frameworks, and JS, you might try injecting your own hooks into the browser... (something similar to Electron) or hiring a room of low $ manual workers.  There would also be native requests using things like Curl and/or Beautiful Soup.

@browsermator  well you guess well xdd,  im using driver less version of selenium  it can only open links and get html and intercept requests but is undetectable in ok 90% of tasks,  unfortunately for this task im using tor proxy and cause of that its detecting me i developed sys to analyze photos ok 85% of accuracy but we all know it work on detecting cdp or fingerprint analysis methods, im low on budget thats why capta slowing aips are not an option the same with better proxies i will analyze your idea and test it ,also you know something about xlib and virtual desktops ?

bot detection can be much more than just detecting cdp, wire protocol, or "fingerprint" details...  they'll also test for synthetic events (such as events without "isTrusted" true bool) and bot-like behavior.  I know nothing about xlib and virtual desktops... should probably start another question for that.

@browsermator thank for your advise in regards of 1st question im analyzing your idea it seams to be promising for now
